# Custom short citations (Biblatex Verbose)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to suppress the comma in the postnotes but just in the short citations. In my MWE I get

> Stratoydaki-White, «Patriarch Photios - A Christian Humanist», cit., p.
>   196.

instead of

> Stratoydaki-White, «Patriarch Photios - A Christian Humanist», cit. p.
>   196.

I tried with the redefinition:

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
```

But it obviously it affects every citation, not just the short ones.

How could I fix the problem?

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@article{Stu:Pat,
    Author = {Despina Stratoydaki-White},
    Date-Added = {2015-11-18 12:39:01 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-11-18 12:40:01 +0000},
    Journal = {The Greek Orthodox Theological Review},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {195-205},
    Title = {Patriarch Photios - A Christian Humanist},
    Volume = {25},
    Year = {1980}}


@article{Szi:Usu,
    Author = {Szidat, Joachim},
    Date-Added = {2017-09-25 13:16:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-09-25 13:17:10 +0000},
    Journal = {Historia. Zeitschrift für Alte Geschichte},
    Pages = {487-508},
    Title = {Die Usurpation des Eugenius},
    Volume = {28},
    Year = {1979}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}   %openany
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

% \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


a\footcite[197-198]{Stu:Pat} \\

b\footcite[488]{Szi:Usu} \\

c\footcite[196]{Stu:Pat}


\end{document}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Mhh, to me that looks more like you would say that the work was cited on p. 196 and not that this is an already cited work and you would like to refer to p. 196. I would not omit the comma here.

Comment: Me neither, but not my publisher unfortunately.

Comment: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{opcit = {cit\adddot\nopunct}}` seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{opcit = {cit\adddot\nopunct}}
```

works for the issue at hand and seems to be the least bad of several bad options.

---

A safer, but more tedious version, introduces a new check if we had an 'op. cit.' citation. That check needs to be done with a toggle, since at the time `\postnotedelim` is printed, the native checks to find out if a citation is 'op. cit.' are not available any more.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2, useprefix=true, giveninits=true, citepages=omit, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx:opcit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:opcit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:opcit}}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\iftoggle{cbx:opcit}{\addspace}{\addcomma\space}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a\footcite[197-198]{sigfridsson}

b\footcite[488]{vizedom:related}

c\footcite[196]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image]