# Fine tuning on a crazy citation style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm almost there. In the past days I built a citation style according to the requests of my publisher.

The hard work was made [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418701/hot-to-custom-split-in-two-ibidem/418710#418710), when we defined the behavior of Idem, Ibidem and a "Ivi".

Unfortunately, putting all the things together, something got broken. In my example, that for this reason cannot be so "minimal", I have two problems:

1. a missing comma between date and postnote in the book driver
2. a colon instead of comma after "Ivi" in footnote 3.

I tried to move things but I managed just to worsen the situation, so I'm begging again for help.

This is the not-so-minimal-WE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@incollection{Rae:Rap,
    Author = {Gilbert Raes},
    Booktitle = {La S. Sindone. Ricerche e studi della commissione di esperti nominata dall'Arcivescovo di Torino},
    Editor = {P. Caramello},
    Pages = {79-83},
    Series = {Supplemento Rivista diocesana torinese},
    Title = {Rapport d'analyse},
    Year = {gennaio 1976}}


@incollection{Rae:His,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Gilbert Raes},
    Booktitle = {Prélèvement sur le linceul effectué le 21 avril 1988 et études du tissu},
    Date-Added = {2017-07-30 14:20:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-02-28 16:02:55 +0000},
    Pages = {71-74},
    Publisher = {\textsc{o.e.i.l.}},
    Title = {Historique de l'échantillon remis le 24 novembre 1973. Problème de la bande latérale. Fibres de coton dans l'échantillon remis au laboratoire d'Oxford},
    Year = {1990}}

@article{Dan:Ind,
    Author = {Avinoam Danin},
    Date-Added = {2017-08-29 20:03:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-08-29 20:04:48 +0000},
    Journal = {Il Telo},
    Pages = {12-21},
    Title = {Indicazioni floreali per l'origine geografica della Sindone di Torino},
    Volume = {II},
    Year = {2001}}

@book{Lan:Rom,
    Address = {Edinburgh},
    Author = {Bertrand Lancon AND Antonia Nevill},
    Publisher = {Edinburgh University Press},
    Title = {Rome in Late Antiquity: Everyday Life and Urban Change, \textsc{ad} 312-609},
    Year = {2000}}


@book{Hal:Sul,
    Address = {Vindobonae},
    Editor = {C. Halm},
    Langid = {german},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {C. Geroldi filium bibliopolam academiae},
    Series = {\textsc{csel}},
    Title = {Sulpici Severi libri qui supersunt},
    Year = {1866}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[]{csquotes} %autostyle,italian=guillemets
\usepackage{xpatch}     
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            babel=other,                        % Ed / hrsg / Éd
            useprefix=true,                 
            giveninits=true,    
         indexing=cite,                 % 
            citepages=permit,                   % 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}    
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}                   % Journaltitle in double inverted commas
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}              % kills "vol."

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, inproceedings]{postnote}{\addcolon\space\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, inproceedings]{multipostnote}{\addcolon\space\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%  Ed/Edd after Editor name 
 \ifnameundef{editor}
 {}
 {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
 \clearname{editor}%
 \newunit}%
 \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
 \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

 \xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{%           Editore before title in incollection
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}%
  {%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  }%
  {}{}%


\makeatletter                           % All this shit just to kill a comma between Editor and (Ed.) 
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     {\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}                              % Comma between units
 \xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%                                              % et al. emphatic (xpatch needed)
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}                         % comma instead of AND between multiple authors
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\bibstring{in}\space}                                           % no colon after IN



\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}     % Customising Idem e Ibidem e Ivi
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\textsc{id}},
  idemsm = {\textsc{id}},
  idemsf= {\textsc{id}},
  idemsn = {\textsc{id}},
  idempm = {\textsc{id}},
  idempf = {\textsc{id}},
  idempn = {\textsc{id}},
  idempp = {\textsc{id}},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}}, %  ibidem = {Ibid\adddot},
  ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
  opcit  = {cit\adddot},
  loccit = {loc\adddotspace cit\adddot},
}


\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}


\DefineBibliographyExtras{italian}{%            %% I always want the short dash
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{%
    -\penalty\hyphenpenalty}}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}        % Title emphatic in shorthands

  \renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%                 "cit" in tondo              
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%               Comma before di cit.
    \bibstring{opcit}}}                   

   \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{opcit = {cit\adddot\nopunct}}        % no comma after cit. If it doesn't work see:
                                                % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417733/custom-short-citations-biblatex-verbose/418206#418206



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%             First publisher, then location
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%                            
\iffieldundef{series}{}{%
  \printtext[parens]{\printfield{series}%\addcomma%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%                  %  pub+loc+year before ser+num
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock 
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newblock\nopunct%            
    \usebibmacro{series+number}\addcomma%       Comma added by me. It works, but is this the right place?
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}



\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\textit{Incollection:}\\
\cite[80]{Rae:Rap}\\

\textit{Book without author but with series}\\
\cite[55-56]{Hal:Sul}\\

\textit{Book}\\
\cite[55-56]{Lan:Rom}\\

\textit{Article with specific pagerange cited}\\
\cite[19-20]{Dan:Ind}\\

First cite\footcite[1]{Rae:Rap}, Same work, same page->ibidem\footcite[1]{Rae:Rap}, Same work, different page->ivi\footcite[3]{Rae:Rap} and same author, different work->idem\footcite[4]{Rae:His}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly: In point (2) you are saying that currently you see a colon (so do I) and that you want a comma instead?

Comment: Yes, as it was after your work here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418701/hot-to-custom-split-in-two-ibidem/418710#418710

Comment: Can you explain in more details what your modifications of the `book` driver were supposed to achieve? They seem to be problematic and I would like to re-write them, but I would need to know what the expected outcome should be.

Comment: Yes, I messed it to achieve the sorting order you see: Auhor, title, Publisher, Location year (series), postnotes. So basically to have pub+loc+year before ser+num, plus some minor issues like the comma after the series (even though I think that's not the right place to put it). However, in the example everything is fine except the two things I mentioned.

Comment: The thing is: If I change something, there are cases where the output would differ and I'm not sure if those cases matter. You have, for example, placed the series+number after the `related` function at the moment. I would move it before the `related` loop, but of course then the output will be different if `related` is used. So I can compare with the MWE but that does not contain all possible cases ...

Comment: Your `@incollection`s and `@collection` s can also have a series. Should that also move to the end like for `@book`s or should it stay?

Comment: Ah blast. I was asking because the `series` in `Rae:Rap` is not after the year. Do you want me to change my answer to move the series for `@(in)?(book|collection|proceedings)` as well?

Comment: Actually, let's leave them there, at least for the moment

Comment: May be, you can be a little more specific in title than "Fine tuning on a crazy citation style"... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the different separator for pages in the postnote by abusing the `citepages=separate` option.

We *do not* redefine `\postnotedelim` to be a colon and we do not meddle with the `postnote` and `multipostnote` formats, instead we only need

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote:pages}{%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{postnote}}
```

I modified a few other things as well, so please check the code and the output carefully. (Warning! The MWE uses `filecontents` and will overwrite a `.bib` file with the same base name as the `.tex` file if compiled. Test this in a separate directory to make sure this does not damage your production environment.) I have removed your comments and added comments myself to explain little code changes.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Rae:Rap,
    Author = {Gilbert Raes},
    Booktitle = {La S. Sindone. Ricerche e studi della commissione di esperti nominata dall'Arcivescovo di Torino},
    Editor = {P. Caramello},
    Pages = {79-83},
    Series = {Supplemento Rivista diocesana torinese},
    Title = {Rapport d'analyse},
    date = {1976-01}}% gennaio 1976 is not a valid year value. Use this (and dateabbrev=false) instead

@incollection{Rae:His,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Gilbert Raes},
    Booktitle = {Prélèvement sur le linceul effectué le 21 avril 1988 et études du tissu},
    Pages = {71-74},
    Publisher = {\textsc{o.e.i.l.}},
    Title = {Historique de l'échantillon remis le 24 novembre 1973. Problème de la bande latérale. Fibres de coton dans l'échantillon remis au laboratoire d'Oxford},
    Year = {1990}}

@article{Dan:Ind,
    Author = {Avinoam Danin},
    Journal = {Il Telo},
    Pages = {12-21},
    Title = {Indicazioni floreali per l'origine geografica della Sindone di Torino},
    Volume = {II},
    Year = {2001}}

@book{Lan:Rom,
    Address = {Edinburgh},
    Author = {Bertrand Lancon AND Antonia Nevill},
    Publisher = {Edinburgh University Press},
    Title = {Rome in Late Antiquity: Everyday Life and Urban Change, \textsc{ad} 312-609},
    Year = {2000}}


@book{Hal:Sul,
    Address = {Vindobonae},
    Editor = {C. Halm},
    Langid = {german},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {C. Geroldi filium bibliopolam academiae},
    Series = {\textsc{csel}},
    Title = {Sulpici Severi libri qui supersunt},
    Year = {1866}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,% use new option name
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=cite,%
            citepages=separate,%
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}

% the colon/comma issues for pages together with citepages=separate
\renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote:pages}{%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
 \ifnameundef{editor}
   {}
   {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
    \clearname{editor}%
    \newunit}%
 \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
 \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}%
  {%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  }%
  {}{}%


% NEW
% All this shit just to kill a comma between Editor and (Ed.)
% nope, it's easier
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
% I assume you also have ?
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
% same for translator
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

% NEW
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% comma instead of AND between multiple authors

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\bibstring{in}\space}

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem   = {\textsc{id}},
  idemsm = {\textsc{id}},
  idemsf = {\textsc{id}},
  idemsn = {\textsc{id}},
  idempm = {\textsc{id}},
  idempf = {\textsc{id}},
  idempn = {\textsc{id}},
  idempp = {\textsc{id}},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
  opcit  = {cit\adddot\nopunct},
  loccit = {loc\adddotspace cit\adddot},
}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}


\DefineBibliographyExtras{italian}{%
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{%
    -\penalty\hyphenpenalty}}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

% I don't think you needed the redefinition of cite:title.

% slightly simplified
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}


% modified
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textit{Incollection:}\\
\cite[80]{Rae:Rap}\\

\textit{Book without author but with series}\\
\cite[55-56]{Hal:Sul}\\

\textit{Book}\\
\cite[55-56]{Lan:Rom}\\

\textit{Article with specific pagerange cited}\\
\cite[19-20]{Dan:Ind}\\

First cite\footcite[1]{Rae:Rap}, Same work, same page->ibidem\footcite[1]{Rae:Rap}, Same work, different page->ivi\footcite[3]{Rae:Rap} and same author, different work->idem\footcite[4]{Rae:His}

\footcite{westfahl:frontier}

\footcite{westfahl:space}

\footcite[1]{Rae:Rap}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need to set the "idem" thing for several languages at once,

```
\newcommand*{\mklangidem}[1]{%
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{#1}{%
    idem   = {\textsc{id}},
    idemsm = {\textsc{id}},
    idemsf = {\textsc{id}},
    idemsn = {\textsc{id}},
    idempm = {\textsc{id}},
    idempf = {\textsc{id}},
    idempn = {\textsc{id}},
    idempp = {\textsc{id}},
    ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}},
    ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
    opcit  = {cit\adddot\nopunct},
    loccit = {loc\adddotspace cit\adddot},
  }}

\forcsvlist{\mklangidem}{english,italian}
```

might come in handy. At the moment there is no catch-all language override, there was a feature request a while ago, but the details have not yet been worked out https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/560

Comment: Oddly enough, it didn't work for me. It crashes on \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

Comment: Your version of `biblatex` is outdated.

Comment: @Teodoro If you don't want to update, you can use `\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}` instead. But my shorter solution to "All this shit just to kill a comma between Editor and (Ed.)" will not work with your old version, either. So you will have to revert to your longer solution.

Comment: I appreciated so much your work that I'm now updating everything (I was still on the 2016 distribution). Probably all my code will explode (and I'm not talking about the bibliography, but about the parallel critical edition that I'm editing) but I had to do it... finger crossed.

Comment: @Teodoro Uhh, updates are always a bit of a gamble if you are in the middle of something important. Fingers crossed that everything goes alright. You would probably have been fine with `\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}` and your old code for the editor issue with your old version of `biblatex`, though.

Comment: I just completed all the updates. The first thing I notice is that in the example we have an inconsistency between footnote 4 (the behavior is correct: ID.) and footnote 6 (idem) although both of them refer to a "same author-same work". What happened there?

Comment: @Teodoro You have `language=auto,` and `autolang=other,` that means that your entries switch language according to their `langid` field. None of your entries have a `langid` field and so they fall back to the main language (Italian), but the entries from `biblatex-examples.bib` have a `langid` and so the citation in footnote 6 goes with the English localisation. We only changed the Italian translation of `idem` to "ID", the English remains "idem".  You otherwise hardly notice the switch since "ed", "pp." and "in" seem to be the same for Italian and English.

Comment: ... So this should not be a problem for you actual document if you never have a `langid` field. You could also work around this by choosing different values for the `language` and `autolang` options.

Comment: Actually I do usually have langid field expressed, I just cut it off in the examples, as well as the other \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{     
    editor... and so on. So could we set the ID for any language, instead?

Comment: @Teodoro OK. The best course of action depends on what you want. If you want your references to switch languages, but you want the "ID" to stay the same, you'll need the `\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}` block above for all languages you use. I have a added a hack to my answer that lets you do that for many languages at once. If you don't want your entries to switch language you probably only want `autolang=hyphen` or even `autolang=none`.