# Customize op. cit. / loc. cit. entries using shorttile field from biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I need to costumize how short titles are printed in footnote citations. To be precise I need to add `(\ldots)\comma\space` between shorttitle and next part of footcite. I already have `biblatex.cfg` with bunch of modifications to verbose-trad2 style, but I can't find what I need to put in `\renewbibmacro*{}`

I've searched here and I've only found this: [Custom short citations (Biblatex Verbose)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417733/custom-short-citations-biblatex-verbose) but I'm not sure how to adjust it for my case, so any help will be much appreciated!

MWE:

bibliografia.bib:

```
@book{      kowalska1,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
title =     {Jeden},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2003}
}
@book{      k,
author =    {K. Maciej},
title =     {Very Long and Verbose Ttile: even with longer subtitle},
shorttitle = {Short Title},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2031}
}
```

texfile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{polish} 
\usepackage[
  style=verbose-trad2,
  sorting=nty,
  isbn=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\begin{document}
ipsum \footcite{k}
Lorem \footcite{kowalska1} 
ipsum \footcite{k}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sourcemap, and add it directly to the field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shorttitle, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={\addspace\bibellipsis}, append] % recommended
      % \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={\unexpanded{\addspace(\ldots)\isdot}}, append] % if you really need the parentheses
    }
  }
}
```

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{polish} 
\usepackage[
  style=verbose-trad2,
  isbn=false,
  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{      kowalska1,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
title =     {Jeden},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2003}
}
@book{      k,
author =    {K. Maciej},
title =     {Very Long and Verbose Ttile: even with longer subtitle},
shorttitle = {Short Title},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2031}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shorttitle, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={\addspace\bibellipsis}, append] % recommended
      % \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={\unexpanded{\addspace(\ldots)\isdot}}, append] % if you really need the parentheses
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
ipsum \footcite{k}
Lorem \footcite{kowalska1} 
ipsum \footcite{k}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've already used solution you've edited out:
`\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addspace(\ldots)\isdot}
    \DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addspace(\ldots)\isdot}`

Comment: @konserw, I did edit it out, because I found a relevant case where it will fail. If you have an entry which has no `shorttitle`, the `\ldots` will be added anyway, which is an outright error... So I do recommend you use the sourcemap instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the field format for `citetitle` directly if we are careful. We need to make sure that we are actually displaying the `shorttitle` at the moment. This is what `\ifshorttitle` does, it checks if a `shorttitle` was used for the `labeltitle` field and if `shorttitle` and `title` are different. We then add `\ifshorttitle{\shorttitlepunct}{}` in the appropriate places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{polish} 
\usepackage[
  style=verbose-trad2,
  isbn=false,
  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\ifshorttitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{labeltitlesource}{shorttitle}}
              and not test {\iffieldsequal{shorttitle}{title}}}}

\newcommand*{\shorttitlepunct}{\addspace\bibellipsis}% or {{\normalfont\addspace\bibellipsis}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\ifshorttitle{\shorttitlepunct}{}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\ifshorttitle{\shorttitlepunct}{}\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {citetitle}{#1\ifshorttitle{\shorttitlepunct}{}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{      kowalska1,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
title =     {Jeden},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2003}
}
@book{      k,
author =    {K. Maciej},
title =     {Very Long and Verbose Ttile: even with longer subtitle},
shorttitle = {Short Title},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2031}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
ipsum \autocite{k}
Lorem \autocite{kowalska1} 
ipsum \autocite{k}
Lorem \autocite{kowalska1} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice trick. Some more learned, I didn't know we could test for which field is currently performing as label.

Comment: Btw, moewe, if I may. I had one particular trouble with my answer which I found strange. I trieded `\addspace(\ldots)\isdot` and `\addspace(\ldots)\addcomma` to the sourcemap. It accepts the `\addspace(\ldots),` as I left it. But either of these constructions, which seem better to me, threw me "undefined control sequence" errors. Do you know why? Are these macros not available when the sourcemap is executed?

Comment: @gusbrs I think the definitions are expanded when the sourcemap is written to the `.bcf` file, this is a problem if some of them are only available in a `biblatex` context, or if the commands are not robust. `fieldvalue={\unexpanded{\addspace\bibellipsis\isdot}}` works.

Comment: Thanks, moewe, I added this to the answer. But I confess I would expect `\DeclareSourcemap` to take care of that. The same way formating directives, as `\DeclareFieldFormat`, do. After all, what goes in `fieldvalue` is not meant to be used outside a `biblatex` context to start with.

Comment: @gusbrs I agree. The thing is that writing to files often expands commands, so we would have to stop that behaviour. I had a quick look at the code and did not immediately have an idea how to solve this. You can open an issue at the bugtracker, maybe PLK has an idea.

Comment: Ok, moewe, I'll do that latter. But my experience tells me, there might well be a reason I haven't considered. :) Btw, I'm assuming this should be reported to `biber`, not to `biblatex`. Is that correct?

Comment: @gusbrs No, this is a `biblatex` thing. The problem happens when `biblatex` writes the `.bcf` file.

Comment: Ok, good thing I asked then. I'll report it later. Thanks.